# Issue with removing cloned element once created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that clones/adds a div element and it's children when a button is clicked, however, when the remove button is clicked, it doesn't seem to be removing the closest div to the remove button. Can you help with this.

```js
$(function() {
  //on click
  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
    //alert($(".input-group").length)
    var
      //get length of selections
      length = $(".input-group").length,
      //create new id
      newId = "selection-" + length,
      //clone first element with new id
      clone = $("#selection").clone().attr("id", newId);
    clone.children('.show-tick').attr('id', 'select-' + length++);
    //append clone on the end
    $("#selections").append(clone);
  });

  $(".btn-secondary").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-group').remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selections">
  <div class="input-group" id="selection">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="icon wb-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    <select class="show-tick" data-plugin="select2" id="select">
      <option>True</option>
      <option>False</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Add new selection</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Remove new selection</button>
```

Comment: What do do mean by `closest()`?

Comment: as I see nothing after remove button so what do you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

To remove last *select* item you should use:

```
$("#selections").find('select').last().remove();
```

In your function:

```
$(".btn-secondary").on("click", function() {
    $("#selections").find('select').last().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the last `.input-group` so replace the last line with this:

```
  $('.input-group').last().remove();
```

The buttons are actually siblings of `#selections` so the point of reference (`this`) doesn't need to be from the button itself. `.closest()` would target ancestor elements of the button and the `.input-group` is more like a "nephew/niece" relation to the buttons. Using the parent container `#selections` or the collection of `.input-group` is sufficient.

### Edit

Added a condition that should the `$('.input-group').length` be 1, that it be spared from being deleted, otherwise, there'd be nothing to clone.

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  //on click
  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
    //alert($(".input-group").length)
    var
      //get length of selections
      length = $(".input-group").length,
      //create new id
      newId = "selection-" + length,
      //clone first element with new id
      clone = $("#selection").clone(true, true).attr("id", newId);
      clone.find('.show-tick').attr('id', 'select-' + length++);
    //append clone on the end
    $("#selections").append(clone);
  });

  $(".btn-secondary").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".input-group").length > 1) {
      $('.input-group').last().remove();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<div id="selections">
  <div class="input-group" id="selection">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="icon wb-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <select class="show-tick" data-plugin="select2" id="select">
      <option>True</option>
      <option>False</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left: 
    30px;">
    Add new selection
    </button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="margin-left: 
    30px;">
    Remove new selection
    </button>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

or do just

```html
$('#selections div:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:last-child` selector:

```
$('.input-group:last-child').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is various way you can do inside your click handler:

```
$("#selections .input-group:last-child").remove();
// Or
$(".input-group:last-child", "#selections").remove();
// Or
$(".input-group", "#selections").last().remove();
```

Using the first way:

```js
$(function() {
  //on click
  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
    //alert($(".input-group").length)
    var
      //get length of selections
      length = $(".input-group").length,
      //create new id
      newId = "selection-" + length,
      //clone first element with new id
      clone = $("#selection").clone().attr("id", newId);
    clone.children('.show-tick').attr('id', 'select-' + length++);
    //append clone on the end
    $("#selections").append(clone);
  });

  $(".btn-secondary").on("click", function() {
    $("#selections .input-group:last-child").remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selections">
  <div class="input-group" id="selection">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="icon wb-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    <select class="show-tick" data-plugin="select2" id="select">
      <option>True</option>
      <option>False</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Add new selection</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Remove new selection</button>
```

You should also add a check that, there is at least 1 `.input-group` element left for add button to work, because if there is no `.input-group` element, which element you'll clone? So, add a check like:

```js
$(function() {
  //on click
  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
    //alert($(".input-group").length)
    var
      //get length of selections
      length = $(".input-group").length,
      //create new id
      newId = "selection-" + length,
      //clone first element with new id
      clone = $("#selection").clone().attr("id", newId);
    clone.children('.show-tick').attr('id', 'select-' + length++);
    //append clone on the end
    $("#selections").append(clone);
  });

  $(".btn-secondary").on("click", function() {
    var length = $(".input-group").length;
    if (length === 1) {
        alert("Can not delete the last element");
        return;
    }
    
    $("#selections .input-group:last-child").remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selections">
  <div class="input-group" id="selection">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="icon wb-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    <select class="show-tick" data-plugin="select2" id="select">
      <option>True</option>
      <option>False</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Add new selection</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Remove new selection</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the last method `$("#selections").children("div").last().remove();`

```js
$(function() {
  //on click
  $(".btn-primary").on("click", function() {
    //alert($(".input-group").length)
    var
      //get length of selections
      length = $(".input-group").length,
      //create new id
      newId = "selection-" + length,
      //clone first element with new id
      clone = $("#selection").clone().attr("id", newId);
    clone.children('.show-tick').attr('id', 'select-' + length++);
    //append clone on the end
    $("#selections").append(clone);
  });

  $(".btn-secondary").on("click", function() {
    $("#selections").children("div").last().remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selections">
  <div class="input-group" id="selection">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="icon wb-menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    <select class="show-tick" data-plugin="select2" id="select">
      <option>True</option>
      <option>False</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Add new selection</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="margin-left:30px;">Remove new selection</button>
```